Why is $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ uncountable?
In the book Measure and Integral : An introduction to real analysis, in chapter 8 Lp spaces, theorem 8.18, the authors give a counterexample to show that $l^\infty$ is not separable:


Question: why is this set of sequences uncountable? I am given an answer that it is related to Cantor's diagonal argument. But how can I write this formally?

We know the interval $[0, 1]$ is uncountable. You can think of the binary expansions of all numbers in $[0, 1]$. This will give you an uncountable collection of sequences.

so is it enough if i just repeat the proof in Cantor's diagonal argument?

Yes exactly. That argument gives you the existence of uncountable binary sequences. Now each element of the sequence is a binary expansion for the different numbers on $[0, 1]$. Therefore, they must differ at some index, i.e. there must be some index where one sequence is 1 and the other one is 0. Therefore, their $l_\infty$ norm is 1.

ok , thanks a lot

Please don’t use
images instead of typing your formulas

Simpler and more direct argument than @Debarghya's suggestion (avoiding the trouble that some numbers have two binary expansions, one proper and one improper i.e. 'ending' with an infinite tail of ones): you can easily define a bijection between your set of binary sequences and the powerset  $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ of $\Bbb N$. Now, the proof that $|\mathcal P(X)|>|X|$ for every set $X$ is standard.

I finally get it, let me conclude what i have just learned

Big thanks to @Debarghya and @AnneBauva
Conclusion:
1)Lemmas and theorems (I looked it up in my textbook):
(1)If E is a set, then there does not exist a surjective mapping  $E \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(E)$
(2)$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable. (Implied by (1), there is no surjection $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ )
(3)For every set $E$ , $|E| < |\mathcal{P}(E)|$ (again , thank you @AnneBauva for reminding me this)
(again , thank you @AnneBauva for reminding me this)
From @AnneBauva (the post Prove that $\mathcal{P}(A) \sim \{0,1\}^A$, but i think that this post Finding a correspondence between $\{0,1\}^A$ and $\mathcal P(A)$, the rest is actually a "modified" answer from the latter) we can construct a bijective function $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ as follow:
For a function $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$, let $\mathbb{N}_f$ be the set of elements of $\mathbb{N}$ that are mapped to 1 by $f$. That is, $n \in  \mathbb{N}_f$ if and only if $f(n)=1$.
Consider the map $\Phi(f) =\mathbb{N}_f$.
Now  if $f\ne g$, there is an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $f(n)=0$ and $g(n)=1$ (or  $f(n)=1$ and $g(n)=0$).
Then $\mathbb{N}_f \ne \mathbb{N}_g$. So $\Phi$ is one-to-one.
Now let $B\in{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$. Define $f(x)=\cases{1,&x $\in$ B\cr 0,&x $\notin$ B }$
Then $\Phi(f)=B$.  This shows that $\Phi$ is onto ${\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$
So $|\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}|=|{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})|$, and by lemma (2), $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable.
